# CakePHP themed plugin view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to theme a plugin's view? I have a mobile theme for mobile devices and would like to use different view files for a plugins app/views as well. I have tried app/views/themed/THEME/plugin/... and /app/plugins/PLUGIN/views/themed/THEME/...none seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cakephp 2.x supports this without having to make any code changes:

If you (can) convert to using cakephp 2.x then yes you can (automatically). The view paths for a theme 'mytheme' and a plugin 'Permissions' would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/View/Themed/Mytheme/Plugin/Permissions/
    [1] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/View/Themed/Mytheme/
    [2] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/View/Plugin/Permissions/
    [3] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/Plugin/Permissions/View/
    [4] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/View/
    [5] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/lib/Cake/View/
    [6] => /var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/View/
)
```

So if you had Users/index.ctp in the plugin and wanted to override it you would edit:

```
/var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/View/Themed/Mytheme/Plugin/Permissions/Users/index.ctp
```

for the themed version OR:

```
/var/vhosts/Project/htdocs/app/View/Plugin/Permissions/Users/index.ctp
```

for the non themed version

Answer (score 5):

Copy content of your theme to:
**app/views/themed/THEMENAME/plugins/PLUGINNAME/**
Create a **ThemePluginsView** class on **app/libs/view/theme_plugins.php**

```
// app/libs/view/theme_plugins.php
if (!class_exists('ThemeView'))
    App::import('Core', 'view/theme');

class ThemePluginsView extends ThemeView {

    function __construct(&$controller, $register = true) {
        parent::__construct($controller, $register);
    }

    function _paths($plugin = null, $cached = true) {
        $paths = parent::_paths($plugin, $cached);
        if (!is_string($plugin) || empty($plugin) || empty($this->theme))
            return $paths;
        // add app/plugins/PLUGIN/views/themed/THEME path 
        $dirPath = APP . 'plugins' . DS . $plugin . DS . 'views' . DS . 'themed' . DS . $this->theme . DS;
        if (is_dir($dirPath))
            $paths = array_merge(array($dirPath), $paths);
        return $paths;
    }
}
```

Then call it on your app_controller on beforeFilter() or usual controller on beforeFilter() like:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  if (!class_exists('ThemePluginsView'))
    App::import('Core', 'view/theme_plugins');
  $this->view = 'ThemePlugins';
  $this->theme = 'THEME_NAME';
}
```

Hope it helps